# Autocomplete pegando dados de um json de uma url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho essa jquery

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $('[id="franchise"]').autocomplete({
          source: "/ajax_calls/search/",
          minLength: 3,
          open: function(){
              setTimeout(function () {
                  $('.ui-autocomplete').css('z-index', 99);
              }, 0);
          }
        });
    });
  </script>
```

que faz a funçao de autocomplete, pegando os dados da url "/ajax_calls/search/".
Essa URL citada, dispões os dados em forma de lista, da seguinte maneira:

```
['OPCAO 1', 'OPCAO 2', ...]
```

E tudo funciona normalmente... busca os dados corretamente e traz no campo do autocomplete..

Mas agora eu alterei a pagina e ela está me trazendo os dados de uma maneira um pouco diferente. Traz todas as informações dentro de **objects**:

```
{
    "objects": ['OPCAO 1', 'OPCAO 2', ...]
}
```

Com essa alteração, o autocomplete deixou de funcionar.. Como posso ajustar meu jquery para conseguir ler essa nova disposicao dos dados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes estava vindo como array e agora como um JSON. Então você deve usar uma função no `source` recebendo o response como JSON e retornando a array dentro de `objects`, filtrando a array com o que foi digitado no campo:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
  $('#franchise').autocomplete({
   source: function (request, response) {
      $.getJSON("/ajax_calls/search/", function (data) {
         response(data.objects.filter(function(e){
            return ~e.indexOf(request.term);
         }));
      });
    },
    minLength: 3,
    open: function(){
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.ui-autocomplete').css('z-index', 99);
        }, 0);
    }
  });

});
```

Outra forma é puxar a array toda de uma vez com uma só requisição e colocar no `source` do Autocomplete. Desta forma não haverá requisição ao servidor toda vez que algo é digitado no campo:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
  $.getJSON("/ajax_calls/search/", function (data) {
     var fonte = data.objects;
     $('#franchise').autocomplete({
      source: fonte,
       minLength: 3,
       open: function(){
           setTimeout(function () {
               $('.ui-autocomplete').css('z-index', 99);
           }, 0);
       }
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: Cara, eu até tinha aceitado ja sua resposta.. 
Mas percebi agora que na verdade o autocomplete esta trazendo TODO o conteudo da pagina e nao esta 'filtrando' pelo o que eu escrevo no campo.

Comment: Vc disse que está retornando o objeto

Comment: Isso... traz o objeto inteiro. E nao apenas os itens que coincidem com a digitação

Comment: Resposta editada. Agora deve funcionar

Comment: Adicionei uma segunda forma que acho até melhor porque não onera muito o servidor.

Comment: Boa!! Muito obrigado